# python selenium instagrambot - for i in range loop (if statement)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instagram

Pardon me im a noobie what it comes to coding.
okay so my problem is about for i in loop, I couldnt find answer from anywhere and tried many different thing so I decided to ask from here.

so basically the bot goes for 1 hashtag and clicks on picture and after that it keeps liking and following them in order and the problem comes when Ive already followed that person.
so I tried to go for the (if) statement to unfollow if its already followed.

the loops goes fine for one round for example lets say the first picture it goes for like and then follows.. after that it doesnt click the next arrow and it clicks like and unfollow but this time it gets error because reasons?

pardon me I couldnt get the code look any cleaner than this + im not sure if (else:) is needed here.

code:`

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe" 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://instagram.com")
sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//input[@name=\"username\"]"))\
.send_keys(("usernamehere"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(("//input[@name=\"password\"]"))\
.send_keys(("passwordhere"))
driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]/button'))\
    .click()
sleep(4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/div/div/button'))\
    .click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(('/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[2]'))\
    .click()
hashtag_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input'))
hashtag_input.send_keys("hashtagsomething")
sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[1]'))\
    .click()
sleep(4)
#clicks first picture
driver.find_element_by_xpath(('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/div'))\
    .click()
sleep(2)
for i in range(100):
    #likes
 driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/div[3]/section[1]/span[1]
/button")\
    .click()
    sleep(2)
    #follows
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/article/header/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/button")\
    .click()
    sleep(2)
    #if already following
myelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]")
if  myelement.is_displayed():
    myelement.click()
    # clicksnextarrow
else: driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/a[2]")\
.click()
sleep(3)
```

`
Errors im getting are:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Omistaja\Desktop\sublime\seleniumtesti.py", line 43, in 
myelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]")
File "C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
File "C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
File "C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\Omistaja\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]"}
(Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)

thanks for your time

Comment: thanks for asking your question. Could you spend some time formatting the code, give more detail on what exactly are you trying to achieve, what else did you try and why it failed? Also, please share if you are getting any error messages. From the first look, your code may just have a wrong indentation and your for loop is in fact empty.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the error output. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: mmm what do you mean by empty? it was working fine without that myelement part, problem come  at the if statement because it will never skip it/ never does the else: part, its supposed to only do the if statement when it clicks "following" and not "follow", before this it was only liking and moving forward so it was endless loop untill like limit was full